# Mapbox integration with geoserver WPS

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, geoserver

We have web mapping application developed using map-box react. I need to integrate WPS layer from geo-server (hosted by another internal team). I am looking some guidance or code example to  use geoserver WPS request into Map-box . Basically I making post request to WPS request geoserver

```
https://geoserver.corp.org/geoserver/wps
```

with body

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>vec:Clip</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:ids="https://www.company.com/data">
            <wfs:Query typeName="ids:layer-v2021"/>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>clip</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json"><![CDATA[{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -109.233808437350092, 45.233555724343631 ], [ -109.233804460591571, 45.229780342422565 ], [ -109.238724458196486, 45.229829896684677 ], [ -109.237834057540809, 45.233473386592827 ], [ -109.233808437350092, 45.233555724343631 ] ] ] }]]></wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

I need to pass the complexData parameter dynamically and visualize the output response in Map component. Any basic code samples/examples would be highly appreciated.

I created an sample [react project](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/tree/7.1-release/examples/get-started) and looking for options